# Having problems implementing multithreading with a sharepoint file download script

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a script that enumerates all folders in a sharepoint site, and downloads all files. However, it takes too long so I want to speed it up with multithreading.
Here is the download script without multithreading.

```
import os
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
from office365.sharepoint.folders.folder import Folder
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
import concurrent.futures
import itertools
import threading
#import timing
USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "pwd"
SHAREPOINT_SITE = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site"



#file_lock = threading.Lock()
def auth(site):
        ctx = ClientContext(site).with_credentials(
            UserCredential(
                USERNAME,
                PASSWORD
            )
        )
        return ctx

def enum_folder(parent_folder,l):
    
    """ :type parent_folder: Folder
    :type action: (Folder)-> None """
   
    parent_folder.expand(["Folders"]).get().execute_query()
    #print(parent_folder.serverRelativeUrl)
    l.append(parent_folder.serverRelativeUrl)
    for folder in parent_folder.folders:
        enum_folder(folder, l)

def download_file(file, transformed_path):
    print("Downloading ", file.name)
    download_file_name = os.path.join(transformed_path, file.name)
    isExist = os.path.exists(download_file_name)
    if not isExist:
        with open(download_file_name, "wb") as local_file:
            file.download(local_file).execute_query()
        print(f"Downloaded {download_file_name}")
    else:
        print(f"{download_file_name} exists already.")
        return 

def download_folder_files(folder_path,ctx):
     if "Forms" not in folder_path:
        transformed_path = f"Downloads1{folder_path.replace('/sites', '').replace('/Shared Documents', '')}"
        print("Downloading for the folder: ",transformed_path)

        isExist= os.path.exists(transformed_path)
        if not isExist:
            os.makedirs(transformed_path)

        sub_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_path)
        sub_folder.expand(["Files", "Folders"]).get().execute_query()
        files.append(sub_folder.files)
        for file in sub_folder.files:
             download_file(file,transformed_path)
        
            
l=[]
files=[]
ctx =  auth(SHAREPOINT_SITE)
root_folder = ctx.web.default_document_library().root_folder
enum_folder(root_folder,l)
for sub_folder in l:
    download_folder_files(sub_folder, ctx)

        

print ("DONE!")
```

I tried to implement multithreading with concurrent.futures. Problem is after trying to implement it, some files are empty.
I tried to use executor.map on  download_file and on download_folder_files functions.

Comment: I'm a little confused here.  You presented a program that works, but it's slow.  You told us about another program, which doesn't work.  You didn't present that one.  How do you expect us to help you?  I'm not trying to be difficult, but you can't expect other people to guess why an unseen program doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be related to the `download_file` function since multiple threads may try to write to the same file simultaneously. You may need to add a file_lock to ensure that the file writing do not interfere with others when running in multiple threads:

```
import os
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
from office365.sharepoint.folders.folder import Folder
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
import concurrent.futures
import threading

# ... (the rest of your code remains the same)

# Create a lock for file writes
file_lock = threading.Lock()

def download_file(file, transformed_path):
    print("Downloading ", file.name)
    download_file_name = os.path.join(transformed_path, file.name)
    isExist = os.path.exists(download_file_name)
    if not isExist:
        with file_lock:  # Lock the file write operation
            with open(download_file_name, "wb") as local_file:
                file.download(local_file).execute_query()
            print(f"Downloaded {download_file_name}")
    else:
        print(f"{download_file_name} exists already.")
    return

# ... (the rest of your code remains the same)

# Define a function to download a folder
def download_folder(folder_path, ctx):
    if "Forms" not in folder_path:
        transformed_path = f"Downloads1{folder_path.replace('/sites', '').replace('/Shared Documents', '')}"
        print("Downloading for the folder: ", transformed_path)

        isExist = os.path.exists(transformed_path)
        if not isExist:
            os.makedirs(transformed_path)

        sub_folder = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_path)
        sub_folder.expand(["Files", "Folders"]).get().execute_query()
        files = sub_folder.files
        for file in files:
            download_file(file, transformed_path)

# ... (the rest of your code remains the same)

l = []
files = []
ctx = auth(SHAREPOINT_SITE)
root_folder = ctx.web.default_document_library().root_folder
enum_folder(root_folder, l)

# Use concurrent.futures to download folders and files in parallel
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    executor.map(download_folder, l, itertools.repeat(ctx))

print("DONE!")
```

Comment: I did try something like that (you may notice the commented line in the original code) but the issue still remains!
 Now i tried your version, and no difference, some files still come out empty (some are .mp4/.pptx/.docx/.pdf ..)

Comment: if you are concerned about writing a file twice, then use the `asyncio` module...